# SharePoint 2013 Contribute permissions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I have a `contribute` permission on SharePoint 2013 Site. Can I open that SharePoint site in `visual studio` and design it?

Can we use current user filter webpart for contribute permission site. If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

No, the ``contribute```permission level does not have the needed rights to customize.

Not with Visual Studio, **not with SharePoint Designer**

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L01dt.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `Visual Studio` is to `Create->Develop->Deploy` solutions for a SharePoint site, and you must have permissions on a Site to perform such activities.

As mentioned in your question, where you look to design the SharePoint Site.

I can say that no you cannot open a `SharePoint` Site in `VS` and perform design related tasks such as updating `Master Pages, CSS, etc`, But only develop new such files and then deploy to use.

You can make use of [`SharePoint Designer 2013`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35491) (A free tool by Microsoft) which can help you in designing the existing master pages, css files etc on a SharePoint Site.